# MACD Indicator binance

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, indicator, binance

I am really beginner in programming / python.

I don't have the MACD INDICATOR in python.

for MACD indicator, how to say ' when the 2 lines are crossing (histograms flip from down to up) and vice versa, so buy '

I can do the buy order, but how to write the cross/flip action.

I am trying with python on binance.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? What errors?

Comment: thanks, done, you can see my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished my code for MACD,
MACD done by,
1.Calculate a 12-period EMA of the price for the chosen time period.
raw['EMA12'] = raw.close.ewm(span=12).mean().dropna()
2.Calculate a 26-period EMA of the price for the chosen time period.
raw['EMA26'] = raw.close.ewm(span=26).mean().dropna()
3.Subtract the 26-period EMA from the 12-period EMA.
raw['diffEMA'] = raw.EMA12 - raw.EMA26
4.Calculate a nine-period EMA of the result obtained from step 3.
raw['EMA9diff'] = raw.diffEMA.ewm(span = 9).mean().dropna()
5. histograms / MACD signal line
raw['MACDline'] = raw['diffEMA'] - raw['EMA9diff']